# RegEx to accept numbers less then -50.0 or greater than 80.0

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to find a JavaScript regular expression to accept numbers less then -50.0 or greater than 80.0.

Expression below does not work:

```
 /^([-][5][0]\.[0]|[-][0-4][0-9]\.[0-9]|[-][0-9]\.[0-9])|([0]\.[0]|[1-9]\.[0-9]|[0-7][0-9]\.[0-9]|[8][0]\.[0])$/
```

Comment: This is part of knockoutJS validation - the params argument takes regex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RegEx is used for pattern matching, not for something like this. Just parse the input as a number and compare its value.

```
function checkValue(input){
    var number = parseInt(input);
    if (number === NaN) throw new Error('input was not a number') /* error checking */
    if (number < -50 || number > 80) return true;
   return false;
}
```

**Edit:** you should try to do some form of validation upstream if you can. RegEx is not suited for this. Feel free to post more of the context code and we can see how to best validate here.

Comment: Made a live working demo for it , check it out http://hangupin.com/editor/?id=5512f98c5a522 +1

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
/(?:^|[^.])(-([56]\d|\d{3,})(?:\.\d{1,2})?\b|\b([89]\d|\d{3,})(?:\.\d{1,2})?\b)/gm
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tJ9cX9/1)

Comment: Hi, can you help me in this question pls http://stackoverflow.com/q/29294046/3492495