# How to access the domain by custom name without changing actual url in next action

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, laravel, url-rewriting

Here is my website

```
www.mywebsite.com/project
```

But i want to aceess it by the name

```
www.mywebsite.com/project/admin
```

and

```
www.mywebsite.com/project/user
```

The content is inside the `project` folder.

How can i do this ?

Here is the `.htaccess` i already have

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

**Note :**

I am using laravel framework

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with htaccess. Your solution will more then likely involve Routing and Controllers.

Comment: So, should i deal it with routing only ?

Comment: admin and user that you mentioned above example must be username .. That must be passed as parameters and must be handled using routes.

http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing#route-parameters

Comment: @ntuple: but i need to change the entire routes right ?

Answer (score 0):

Since, you are using Laravel so you don't need to do anything with .htaccess  as Mike Anthony mention above. You need to put a parameter into your route.

I guess you want to list all projects by user and you have already got project controller. if this correct you can see the example below.

**Exameple**

```
//add this code in /app/Http/routes.php
Route::get('project/{username}', function($username)
{
    $user = User::where('username', $username)->first();
    $projects = $user->projects()->get();
});
```

Note: From the example you need to create relationship between User Model and Project Model